# Android Java how to make a camera preview stereoscopic

Tags: java, android, stream, wowza, stereoscopy

I am using the Wowza gocoder sdk to stream from my Android to a Webpage.

Since I do want to put the Android device into a cardboard I Need to make the camera view stereoscopic. I searched through the docs but could not find anything.

So basically this XML view:

```
    <com.wowza.gocoder.sdk.api.devices.WZCameraView
        android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        wowza:scaleMode="fill"
        wowza:defaultCamera="back"
        wowza:frameSizePreset="frameSize1280x720"/>
```

Needs the be stereoscopic, like ~ 50% for each eye.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with WZCameraView. But why don't you simply put two of'em into a horizontal listview?

Comment: @AhamadAnees the full XML is this https://kopy.io/NMNzF how would you Change it?

Comment: @AhamadAnees The important part is from 13-31 (the camera view)

Comment: the actual view which I want to be stereoscopic (50/50) is from line 13-31 (XML)

Comment: @AhamadAnees hi did you already find a solution for the xml

Comment: Sorry.i tried.but i couldn't